# syntax to set grid width and height in pyecharts?

Tags: python, echarts

Using Pyecharts 1.9.  I wish to change the grid width to 1920px and height to 900px.  I would have hoped to add options to Grid, but this doesn't work.  Readthedocs is for the old API so I just cannot figure it out.  thank you.

A grid with dimensions 1920*900px
'
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Bar, Grid, Line
from pyecharts.faker import Faker

```
grid = (
    Grid()
    .add(bar, grid_opts=opts.GridOpts(pos_bottom="60%"))
    .add(line, grid_opts=opts.GridOpts(pos_top="60%"))
    .render("grid_vertical.html")
)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `init_opts` parameter to pass in `width` and `height` (among other options) to any graphical object in pyecharts.

```py
grid = (
    Grid(init_opts=opts.InitOpts(height="900px", width="1920px"))
    .add(bar, grid_opts=opts.GridOpts(pos_bottom="60%"))
    .add(line, grid_opts=opts.GridOpts(pos_top="60%"))
    .render("grid_vertical.html")
)
```

## Explanation

`init_opts` is an init parameter for the Base class, from which Grid (and others) inherit.

```py
class Base(ChartMixin):
    """
    `Base` is the root class for all graphical class, it provides
    part of the initialization parameters and common methods
    """

    def __init__(self, init_opts: Union[InitOpts, dict] = InitOpts()):
        [...]
```

`init_opts` takes either a `dict` or an `InitOpts` object. Using the latter will allow you to have a much better overview of what you can change, and how.

By inspecting the InitOpts class, you can see that `height` and `width`'s defaults are defined as `900px` and `500px` respectively. You will also see the other options.

```py
class InitOpts(BasicOpts):
    def __init__(
        self,
        width: str = "900px",
        height: str = "500px",
        is_horizontal_center: bool = False,
        chart_id: Optional[str] = None,
        renderer: str = RenderType.CANVAS,
        page_title: str = CurrentConfig.PAGE_TITLE,
        theme: str = ThemeType.WHITE,
        bg_color: Union[str, dict] = None,
        is_fill_bg_color: bool = False,
        js_host: str = "",
        animation_opts: Union[AnimationOpts, dict] = AnimationOpts(),
        aria_opts: Union[AriaOpts, dict] = AriaOpts()
    ):
        [...]
```